# Where is the Bake button in blender 2.9 (Fluid simulation)

Tags: fluid-simulation

Wheres the Bake button in Blender 2.9
I cant find it since theres no tutorials in 2.9 and the manual has no pictures.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Set the cache type from "Replay" to "Modular". Replay will simulate the fluid when you play the animation so it's good for previews, Modular will actually bake it onto the disk.

Comment: The bake button does not appear when you change to Modular.  For me it only appears when I change it to All